# JIRA: depict task dependencies for project planning (like with Gantt Chart)

Tags: jira

I want the parent task to be blocked from the transition to "done" when there are sub tasks which are still in progress.

The purpose is this: 
We have Task 1, Sub-Task 1.1, Sub-Task 1.2. Only when Sub-Task 1.1 is "done" Sub-Task 1.2 can transition from "open" to "in progress". If 1.1 is "in progress", 1.2 can´t be transitioned.

Only when 1.1 and 1.2 are "done", Task 1 can transition to "done".

right now the parent task can still be moved to done when the sub tasks are open. 
Is there any suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the following link from atlassian-doku.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/preventing-issues-from-being-closed-while-their-sub-task-are-still-open-724928276.html